# Flex Default Height of <s:List> too High

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, list, actionscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flex 4: Setting Spark List height to its content height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559415/flex-4-setting-spark-list-height-to-its-content-height)

I have a `<s:List>` in my Flex 4 application which looks like this:

[image]

... and the code that renders it looks like this:

```
<s:VGroup gap="15" width="90%" left="{width * 0.1}">
<!-- Display the list of reviews -->
    <s:List contentBackgroundAlpha="0" borderVisible="true"
            itemRenderer="renderers.ReviewRenderer" dataProvider="{data}"
            top="10" minHeight="1"/>

<!-- Display the review entry form -->
    <pages:ReviewForm width="90%" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Is there a way that I can get the list to exactly fit the height of its contents, instead of having so much extra room at the bottom? I am positive that I do not have anything with the list item that is taking up all of the extra room, as only the area that is shown is given a blue background in the list when I hover my mouse over the list item.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Apparently this question was already asked on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826295/663604

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property named 'measuredHeight'.

Comment: Thank you but that does not make any visual changes.